# Android Toolbar not instantiate in Layout

Tags: themes, toolbar, android-support-library

I am stuck with Android toolbar, I am trying to create a new layout containing toolbar. But it is giving me errors.
[image: app_bar.xml]

I have tried all the question on SO, but could not resolve the thing.
I tried, Invalidating/Caching Restart , Changing AppTheme, Switching to lower version, but nothing worked out.

**Is it something related to Support library because if I change**

> android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

to

> android.widget.Toolbar

Toolbar works, but I need ViewPager as well as SlidingTabLayout and Cordinator Layout, AppBarLyout

Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x.y.activities"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}
```

Style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#002663</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#002663</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#117CBD</item>


    </style>
```

Any Help is appreciated..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a day , I figured out, what was wrong( I was working on an old project) and It had **support v4 library** added in the libs folder (as I was referring to appcompat v7 in my gradle). 
**I deleted that and it worked like magic for me!!!**